# How to pass Object / Class as function's parameter

Tags: swift

Suppose I have this cat class and I make 2 instance of it. I want cat can attack each other

```
class ninjaCat {
   var health : Double = 100.00
   var attack = Double()

   init(attack : Double){
      self.attack = attack
   }

   func thunderClaw(otherCat : ninjaCat){
      health = otherCat.health
      otherCat.health = health - self.attack
   }
}

var NinjaCat1 = ninjaCat(10.60)
var NinjaCat2 = ninjaCat(20.15)

NinjaCat1.thunderClaw(NinjaCat2)
```

Is it posible to pass class object as function parameter?

Comment: What error are you seeing when you run this code?

Comment: Why are you giving `attack` a static initializer (`= Double()`), when you'll be immediately overwriting it in the `init` (`self.attack = attack`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible indeed.  However you should check you code there because your using the attacking cat's current life instead of the target's to compute the remaining life:

```
func thunderClaw(otherCat : ninjaCat){
   otherCat.health = health - self.attack
}
```

should be

```
func thunderClaw(otherCat : ninjaCat){
   otherCat.health = otherCat.health - self.attack
}
```

or simply

```
func thunderClaw(otherCat : ninjaCat){
   otherCat.health -= self.attack
}
```